# Connecting Remote MAMP Pro to AWS Lightsail Instance

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro, amazon-lightsail

I've setup a VPS on Amazon's Lightsail and can connect via FTP (transmit on a mac) fine.

I'm trying to set-up MAMP Pro's Remote section so I can import and publish live sites directly.

I think I'm using all the correct details, but it fails with a Error code: -2201

"Could not connect with your remote server with the provided server address and port."

Transmit doesn't require a port number but MAMP does, I've tried 21 and 22 but all fail.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Per the MAMP Pro doc's located at https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/Remote/ there are a numbe rof methods to connect; each requireing different information. Which method are you attempting to use?